# Vaadin 14 drag over target class not working

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, vaadin

I want to style my drop target when drag target is above it. According to this tutorial https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/dnd/drop-target v-drag-over-target class should  be used automatically when my drag target will be over drop target but my components are not using this class. Example for drag target work correctly. Here is how it looks in my app
[image]

My Css:

```
.v-dragged.pin-fast-access-btn {
    outline: 1px solid hotpink;
    opacity: 1
}
.v-drag-over-target.pin-fast-access-btn{
    outline: 1px solid lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: <s>Your styles target `fast-access-btn` while the DOM tree seems to contain `pin-fast-access-btn` elements. Does fixing the mismatch help?</s> (It did not.)

Option 2: I haven't tried drag'n'drop with Vaadin 14 (I mainly deal with Vaadin 8), but I'd assume the v-drag-over-target should be applied to the drop target rather than the highlighted element. Have you created a drop target for the content card that says Panel 1, or where is your drop target located in the DOM tree?

Comment: sorry i`ve copied here style from other component which has class name fast-access-btn, this is not working there as well. Now i corrected it. In the picture can bee seen that my dragged component has class name pin-fast-access-btn v-dragged so v-dragged is added automatically to class name. Based on this i suppose that my class name for drop target should be something like this: pin-fast-access-btn v-drag-over-target

Comment: Thanks, good to have that ruled out :)  Edited my answer.

Comment: these cards are drag and drop targets for other cards, so this Panel 1 should be drop target. When i`m dropping on it then my cod for drop event is working correctly

Comment: And the drop target is definitely specifically on that element, rather than something you would only see by expanding the inner layers in the DOM tree? You create it the same way than you create the drag source?

Comment: component of these card is implementing DragSource<Card>, DropTarget<Card> and in constructor i`m adding setActive(true);
  setDraggable(true); and then for each card i`m setting addDropListener, addDragStartListener and addDragEndListener so everything is created same way